# Equivalent of Modifying EFCore a Migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

**Objective**

I want something like Modify-Migration after changing something inside the `Migration.cs` file.

**Already Tried**

There are some when I accidentally use the **Annotation** but now I want to **remove that**.
I have tried to remove  this line:
`.Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy",SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),` from here

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "LateFine",
    columns: table => new
    {
        StudentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        FineAmount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_LateFine", x => x.StudentId);
    });
```

And make this change to the database so that the SQL_Server design of my table will look like this:

`Identity Specification: No`

I already know that, using `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` will not produce that annotation in the first place.

This was the previous code

```
class LateFine
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int FineAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my current modification

```
class LateFine
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int FineAmount { get; set; }
}
```

After building the solution, using the `Update-Database` command, I've got this : `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.`

Comment: You could add a new migration, or rollback the previous one.

Comment: Going to a new migration is not possible in that scenario. I want to change the Identity Specification.

Comment: Why is it not possible? You remove the attribute from your mode, then do `dotnet ef migrations add LateFineRemoveAnnotation`, then perform an data base update with `dotnet ef database update`. Thats what migrations in EF Core are for: to propagate changes of the model to the database schema. An migration which is already applied can't be changed w/o rollback or correction migration. EF Core tracks (`__efhistory` table or so) which migrations are applied and they won't be executed anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple migration files already, just roll back to the last migration and then update this modified migration file again.Execute the following commands in order

```
1.Update-database -Migration YourLastMigrationName
2.Update-database -Migration YourAboveModifiedMigrationName
```

Refer to 
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations#reversing-a-migration